How to save matplotlib violinplots with axes? Tried using fig.tight_layout() but the saved plots are without axes or labels or titles
My codes are as follows:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data_to_plot = [avg[0]['Cell Perimeter (unit pixel side)'], avg[1]['Cell Perimeter (unit pixel side)'], avg[2]['Cell Perimeter (unit pixel side)']]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])

# Create the violinplot 
bp = ax.violinplot(data_to_plot) 
fig.tight_layout() 
plt.xticks([1, 2, 3], ['5.5', '12.5', '25']) 
plt.ylabel('Unit pixel side') 
plt.xlabel('Glucose concentration (mM)') 
plt.title('Cell perimeter axis distribution') 
fig.savefig('Cell perimeter distrution.tiff') 
plt.savefig('Cell perimeter distribution.jpg') 
plt.show()

I tried adding fig.tight_layout(), but it is still not working, and gave me warning as follows:
UserWarning: This figure includes Axes that are not compatible with tight_layout, so results might be incorrect.
fig.tight_layout()
I also tried fig.patch.set_facecolor('xkcd:white'), and it is not working.
Thank you very much for helping out.

Tight layout requires the axes to be added as part of a subplot arrangement.  Try using add_subplot instead of add_axes.

fig, ax = plt.subplots() is a more canonical way to get the figure and axis.

Also note that tight_layout should be called after adding labels, ticks etc.

fig, ax = plt.subplots(layout='constrained') and then do not call plt.tight_layout().

I tried to correct the code, here's what i typed:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data_to_plot = [
    [5.1, 5.3, 5.2, 5.6, 5.5],
    [12.1, 12.4, 12.5, 12.3, 12.6],
    [25.1, 25.3, 25.5, 25.2, 25.6]
]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

bp = ax.violinplot(data_to_plot)

ax.set_xticks([1, 2, 3])
ax.set_xticklabels(['5.5', '12.5', '25'])
ax.set_ylabel('Unit pixel side')
ax.set_xlabel('Glucose concentration (mM)')
ax.set_title('Cell perimeter axis distribution')

plt.tight_layout()

fig.savefig('Cell_perimeter_distribution.tiff', bbox_inches="tight", dpi=300)
fig.savefig('Cell_perimeter_distribution.jpg', bbox_inches="tight", dpi=300)

plt.show()

I hope this helps!
